# spark-sftp java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0

Tags: pyspark, spark-sftp

While in local mode everything is running smoothly, when I'm executing application on remote cluster, I'm getting this error:

```
java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException: 0
    at com.springml.spark.sftp.DefaultSource.copiedFile(DefaultSource.scala:287)
    at com.springml.spark.sftp.DefaultSource.writeToTemp(DefaultSource.scala:262)
    at com.springml.spark.sftp.DefaultSource.createRelation(DefaultSource.scala:124)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.datasources.SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.run(SaveIntoDataSourceCommand.scala:45)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult$lzycompute(commands.scala:70)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.sideEffectResult(commands.scala:68)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.command.ExecutedCommandExec.doExecute(commands.scala:86)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:131)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$execute$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan$$anonfun$executeQuery$1.apply(SparkPlan.scala:155)
    at org.apache.spark.rdd.RDDOperationScope$.withScope(RDDOperationScope.scala:151)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.executeQuery(SparkPlan.scala:152)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.SparkPlan.execute(SparkPlan.scala:127)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd$lzycompute(QueryExecution.scala:80)
    at org.apache.spark.sql.execution.QueryExecution.toRdd(QueryExecution.scala:80)
```

Comment: Can you share your sample code here?

Comment: THE CODE :) https://pastebin.com/mZsKHvyH